# ORMLite - OneToOne relation

Tags: java, ormlite, one-to-one

I got next database structure with OneToOne relation:

[**company**] 
company_id (*PK*) 
company_name

[**company_configuration**] 
company_configuration_id (*Autoincrement*, *PK*) 
company_id (*UNIQUE* *KEY*,*FK*) 
company_configuration_v

I have been using [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com) and I have next classes for this two tables:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "company")
public class Company {

    public static final String ID_COMPANY = "company_id";
    public static final String COMPANY_NAME = "company_name";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID_COMPANY)
    private int idCompany;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = COMPANY_NAME)
    private String companyName;


@DatabaseTable(tableName = "company_configuration")
public class CompanyConfiguration {

    public static final String COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_ID = "company_configuration_id";    
    public static final String COMPANY_ID = "company_id";
    public static final String COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_V = "company_configuration_v";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_ID)
    private int idCompanyConfiguration;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true,foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = COMPANY_ID)
    private Company companyId;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = COMPANY_CONFIGURATION_V)
    private String companyConfigurationV;
```

Here is OneToOne relation because I want to divide a table with many columns. 
As you can see in the example above, there is not relation from `Company` class to `CompanyConfiguration` class.
I know that I can add this snippet of code(examle below) into `Company` class, but I don't need a @ForeignCollectionField becaues the collection will contain only one CompanyConfiguration object:

```
@ForeignCollectionField()
private ForeignCollection<CompanyConfiguration> companyConfigurations;
```

I need to add something like this (examle below) into `Company` class and will get the reference from `Company` class to `CompanyConfiguration` class:

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity = CompanyDbConfig.class)
@JoinTable(name = "company_configuration")
@JoinColumn(name = "id_company")
CompanyConfiguration companyConfiguration;
```

Shortly, I want to get Company object using ORMlite. See the example below. After fetching company from the database, I want to have and CompanyConfiguration object within company object.

```
Company company = daoCompany.queryForId(id); //daoCompany is an instance of ORMlite Dao class
```

Is it possible and how to do that using ORMlite?

Comment: Anyone knows the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

I posted an OrmLite question myself so I looked through the unanswered questions to see if there was anything I could answer. Even though this is an old topic, I wanted to take a stab at it in case it could help someone.

I've read your post a few times and I think you're asking how to load the information from two tables into one model. You're separating a rather large table into two in the database but you want it to come back as one model. If that is correct, here's my take on the code. This assumes you want to use objects to build the query instead of passing in a query string.

```
public class CompanyResult
{
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public long ConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConfigurationV { get; set; }
}

var query = _db.From<Company>
                .Join<CompanyConfiguration>((c, cc) => c.idCompany == cc.idCompany)
                .Where(c => c.idCompany == companyId)
                .Select<CompanyConfiguration>((c, cc) = new {
                    CompanyId = c.idCompany,
                    ConfigurationId = cc.idCompanyConfiguration,
                    Name = c.companyName,
                    ConfigurationV - cc.companyConfigurationV
                });
var results = _db.Single<CompanyResult>(query);
```

You'd keep your existing models so they could be used as DTOs. You'd just be using the new model model above to pass back the exact properties you want.

*I wrote this in Notepad++, forgive any typos.